# Using Google Earth Plugin gives me white map

Tags: extjs4.1, google-earth-plugin, sencha-architect

For some reason when using the Google Earth Plugin with EXTJS it just gives me a white map.

Wish I could post an image although my reputation needs some work.

I include the following files when loading my app.

```
https://www.google.com/jsapi
/location_of_file/googleearth/Ext.ux.GEarthPanel-1.3.js
/location_of_file/googleearth/Ext.ux.GEarthPanel-1.3.css
/location_of_file/GoogleEarthStartup.js
```

The startup file contains.

```
google.load("earth", "1");
google.load("maps", "2.xx");
```

Do I need a key with the jsapi?

Please advice.

All browsers are giving me same issue.

Comment: I am trying to implement the plugin now without using the GEarthPanel method. The Panel is quite old and since no-one really worked on it for many years I imagine it's not compulsory any-more.

Answer (score 0):

We have GE plugin loading in an ExtJs container.  HTML looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/globe/Globe.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/ext/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("earth", "1");
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   Ext.onReady(function() {
      Globe.initGlobe();
   });
</script>
...
<body><!--Globe Panel is inserted here from Globe.js by Ext--></body>
```

The javascript class sets up a container with a div that we can target:

```
this.globeContainingPanel = Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
    ...
    renderTo:   Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
       {
            xtype: 'panel',
            region: 'center',
            html: '<div id="map3d"></div>'
       }
    }]
});
```

Then have the GE render to the div panel:

```
window.google.loader.ApiKey = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPgoogle.earth.ex.key';
window.google.loader.KeyVerified = true;
window.google.earth.allowUsageLogging = false;

google.earth.createInstance('map3d', this.initCallback, this.failureCallback);
```

Also, make sure you have the Google Earth plugin installed in your browser.